# How to add Google Custom Search Engine in navigation bar of Twenty thirteen theme of wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, google-custom-search

I added Google Custom Search Engine in my twenty thirteen wordpress theme using the Google CSE plugin.I manage to add the google search box in the side bar but I want to place it in the navigation bar.How do I do it? and also the search box design does not appear as it was configured to in my theme.Please help I need to finish the design fast.

Comment: If you don't take the time to learn [how to ask on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) chances are no one will take the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what i understand you used a plugin to add google search bar to your page but the plugin only allowed you to add it to the sidebar... In your header are widgets enabled? I would enable widgets and add the google search widget there.

Comment: Widget are enable only for footer and sidebar so I can't do that or is there a way of adding widget to header.

Comment: If you know a way without using the plugin I can also try that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I figured it out how to do it.I created a page searchform.php using the code of Google custom search bar.Then I added `<?php include "searchform.php" ?>` in the header.php file ,using CSS I was able to placed it in the appropriate place.